# MapKit not showing custom Annotation pin image on iOS9

Tags: mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotation, ios9, mkannotationview

My code worked fine from iOS 7 to 8. With the update yesterday the custom images on my pins were replaced by the standard pin image.
Any suggestions?

My code:

```
extension ViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView! {

        if annotation is MKUserLocation {
            return nil
        }

        let reuseId = String(stringInterpolationSegment: annotation.coordinate.longitude)

        var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView

        if pinView == nil {

            pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
            pinView!.canShowCallout = true
            pinView!.image = getRightImage(annotation.title!!) 
        }

        let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure) 
        pinView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button

        return pinView
    }
}
```

The function to get the image returns a `UIImage` based on the name:

```
func getRightImage (shopName:String)-> UIImage{

    var correctImage = UIImage()

    switch shopName
    {
    case "Kaisers":
        correctImage = UIImage(named: "Kaisers.jpg")!
    default:
        correctImage = UIImage(named: "sopiconsmall.png")!

    }

    return correctImage
}
```

No the map looks like this:
[image: ios9 without images]

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Instead of creating an **`MKPinAnnotationView`**, create a plain **`MKAnnotationView`**.

The **`MKPinAnnotationView`** subclass tends to ignore the image property since it's designed to show the standard red, green, purple pins only (via the pinColor property).

When you switch to **`MKAnnotationView`**, you'll have to comment out the animatesDrop line as well since that property is specific to **`MKPinAnnotationView`**.

Comment: I had the exact same issue. Your suggested solution fixed it for me, thanks.

Comment: Thanks! that was great.

Comment: Worked great. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: Man, you saved my night! I had this crazy issue that custom pin images were loaded only after second time I opened map. And changing to `MKAnnotationView` fixed the problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Following code works perfectly on all iOS 6 to iOS 9 devices:

```
    - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    // create a proper annotation view, be lazy and don't use the reuse identifier
    MKAnnotationView *view = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                                reuseIdentifier:@"identifier"];

    // create a disclosure button for map kit
    UIButton *disclosure = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];

    [disclosure addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                             action:@selector(disclosureTapped)]];
    view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = disclosure;

       view.enabled = YES;
       view.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"map_pin"];


    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 4

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = String(stringInterpolationSegment: annotation.coordinate.longitude)

    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId)

    if pinView == nil {

        pinView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        pinView!.canShowCallout = true
        pinView!.image = getRightImage(annotation.title!!) 
    }

    let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure) 
    pinView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button

    return pinView
}
```